# get 1st,last,today date

Tags: javascript, date

How do i get today's date, 1st day of current month and last day of current month?

Comment: Retagged; jQuery has no date functions so it's a plain JavaScript question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puhkF/;)

```
var current = new Date();           // this one's pretty self explanatory

console.log('current: ' + current);

var last = new Date();
last.setMonth(last.getMonth() + 1); // go to next month 
last.setDate(0);                    // setting date to 0 is last day of previous month

console.log('last: ' + last);

var first = new Date();
first.setDate(1);                   // setting date to 1 is first day of current month

console.log('first: ' + first);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `Date` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date